# Following series convergent or not?

Tags: real-analysis

If $\sum a_n$ is convergent then is it true that  $\sum a_n \sin n $ isconvergent ? If $a_n$ is positive term then we can easly prove this series is convergent but how to proceed for general series?

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

Consider $a_n = \frac{\sin n}{n}$ for a counterexample. Note that $$\frac{\sin^2 n}{n} = \frac{1 - \cos 2n}{2n}$$

Comment: Then you have to show that $\sum \cos(2n)/n$ is convergent.

Comment: Which it is by the Dirichlet test.  Trying to leave something for OP, ie. "hint"

Comment: Thanks i got that..